# Adding UDP checksum in IP layer after Xfrm transformation

Tags: udp, checksum

I am doing a custom transformation of the packet using xfrm tables (IPv6).  As part of the transformation, I am adding a UDP header (basically putting my data into an UDP a.k.a UDP encapsulation). The transformation is proper.

Since this transformation occurs at the network layer, I am computing the checksum for the UDP header I added. This checksum is reported incorrect by wireshark.  My kernel version is 3.10.  I am unable to use `udp6_hwcsum_outgoing()` because I do not have the "struct sock".

Can anyone guide me on a method in my kernel or any other kernel version, that computes checksum correctly?

I tried the following (all yield wrong values) -

1.

```
skb->csum = csum_partial((char*)uh, sizeof(struct udphdr), skb->csum);
uh->check = csum_ipv6_magic(&(ip6h->saddr), &(ip6h->daddr),htons(uh->len), IPPROTO_UDP, skb->csum);
```

2.

```
~csum_ipv6_magic(&(ip6h->saddr), &(ip6h->daddr),uh->len, IPPROTO_UDP,0);
```

3.

```
csum = skb_checksum(skb, 0, skb->len, 0);
uh->check = udp_v6_check(sub->len, saddr, daddr, csum);
```